# How to create a jpeg file from image extracted from the pdf file using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, itext

I am using iTextSharp for manipulating pdf file in my asp.net web application. I have converted pdf pages into  `iTextSharp.text.Image.Now` I want to save this image files into hard disk named like page1.jpeg...

Is this possible to store  `iTextSharp.text.Image` in to jpeg format in a file ?

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

Comment: These `Image` classes do not imply that their contents are something like bitmap images. Furthermore, iText(Sharp) does not include code rendering to a bitmap. Therefore, painting those `Image` instances to bitmap image files is not possible out-of-the-box but instead require much code.

Comment: iText doesn't render PDF pages to images. I think you're confusing the fact that you can extract images stored in a PDF file, with your desire to render PDF vector data to a raster image.